# Adding a "dynamic" route manually for troubleshooting

Tags: linux, networking, routing

Is there a way to add a route in Linux with the Dynamic flag set?
The reason I want to do this is to troubleshoot an issue where there exist identically static and dynamic routes, and what happen if I try to delete the static route.

We suspect that the dynamic route was removed, and not the static route.

I have tried:

```
route add -net 192.168.100.0/24 gw 192.168.0.1 dyn
```

But `route -n` only show the flags `UG`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ip route add 192.168.100.0/24 via 192.168.0.1
```

could be written as

```
ip r a 192.168.100.0/24 via 192.168.0.1
```

there's some trace found in my history.

```
ip route add 192.168.100.0/24 via 192.168.0.1 scope global dev eth0
```

You could even add a secondary ip address to same link;

```
ip a a 192.168.100.210/24 dev eth0 label eth0:test
```

`ip` is a full featured *iproute2* tool. But as low level, you may have to `ip address add` before `ip route add`... So please, RTFM ;-)

```
man -Pless\ +/^ip.route ip
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I do not see how this command add the route with the D flag.

Comment: I think you misunderstand `dynamic route` meaning. If I rightly understand you ask, you can't. Did you already browse `http://lartc.org` the *linux advanced routing & traffic control* documentation?